# git deletes ALL other branches on push to remote

Tags: git, yocto, bitbake

I have unexpected behaviour from **git** in conjunction with my **yocto** project (it must be related somehow).

This is what happens when pushing updates from a submodule:

```
user@debian:~my_repo/my_submodule$ git branch 
  feature/some_feature
* master
user@debian:~my_repo/my_submodule$ git push origin master
Enumerating objects: 5, done.
Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 429 bytes | 429.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Analyzing objects... (3/3) (39 ms)
remote: Storing packfile... done (240 ms)
remote: Storing index... done (60 ms)
To <some_path>/my_submodule.git
 - [deleted]         feature/some_feature
   a46b3d5..b1418de  master -> master
user@debian:~my_repo/my_submodule$ git branch 
* master
user@debian:~my_repo/my_submodule$
```

For **git** to delete the other branches on a push master:master like this is completely new to me.

To give more detail, the git repo source is checked out via a yocto project:

```
devtool modify my_repo
```

I'm fairly certain that the bitbake/yocto must somehow be reconfiguring git to this behaviour?

EDIT 1:

```
user@debian:~my_repo/my_submodule$ git config -l
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
user.name=Jimmy Pettersson
user.email=jimmy.pettersson@<>
diff.tool=bc3
difftool.bc3.trustexitcode=true
merge.tool=bc3
mergetool.bc3.trustexitcode=true
filter.lfs.required=true
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
color.ui=auto
http.http:<URL>.extraheader=Authorization: Basic <SOME_MD5_HASH>==
status.submodulesummary=1
submodule.recurse=false
push.recursesubmodules=check
http.https:<URL>.extraheader=Authorization: Basic <SOME_MD5_HASH>==
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.worktree=../../../my_submodule
remote.origin.url=ssh://<some_path>/my_submodule
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/*:refs/*
remote.origin.mirror=true
```

Comment: Maybe you have some hooks? We can't tell without more code

Comment: `git config remote.origin.push` ? `git config remote.origin.mirror` ? `git config push.default` ?

Comment: @Justinas , there are hooks in the parent repository but they are the same as when the repository is checked out outside yocto environment (where this does not happen)

Comment: I made a guess but upon re-reading your output, I'm pretty sure that guess was wrong, so I deleted that comment. In any case, adding the output from `git config -l` (perhaps with `--show-origin` or `--local`) might help here.

Comment: `remote.origin.mirror=true` — that's where I think the problem is. I already tried to get that info in my [previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70708692/git-deletes-all-other-branches-on-push-to-remote?noredirect=1#comment125000544_70708692).